# Make list of buttons clicked

Tags: javascript

Note: I know there may be ways to do this in other languages but I have only learned javascript.

I have an array of objects (food items in this case, each item has a name property). I have this code in a for loop that makes buttons for each item in the array (if the first item in the array has a name of cake then cake's button is called cake, if the item is called fries then the buttons name is fries). I want the user to be able to click the button for each item only once, and when that button is clicked, I want to display a list of each item clicked. The reason why I have var click = item[i].name is because I want each button to have the name of the item. This code makes a button for item in the array but it does not list the items clicked on. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
 <html>
    <head>  
    </head>
    <body>
           <p id="likes">Likes: </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var items=[
{
name:"cake",
price:12
},
{
name:"fries",
price:10
},
{
name:"apple",
price:11
}
];



window.onload = function() {
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

                        var btnItems = document.createElement("button");
                        btnItems.id = "btnItems";
                        btnItems.innerHTML = "Items";

                        var clicks = items[i].name;
                        btnItems.onclick = function () {

                       el.disabled = true;
                       clicks += items[i].name + i;
                       document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "Items Clicked" + clicks;
    }
}
```

Comment: please show complete code for fast solution

Comment: @MrKhan I have updated my question

Comment: Html as well please

Comment: and where is your list for cakes, fries etc?

Comment: My list is inside my javascript file @EugenSunic

Comment: Added that as well @MrKhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style your view as you wish but this should answer your problem

```js
var items = [{
    name: "cake",
    price: 12
  },
  {
    name: "fries",
    price: 10
  },
  {
    name: "apple",
    price: 11
  }
];

for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  const btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.id = "btnItems";
  btn.textContent = items[i].name;

  btn.onclick = function(el) {
    // disable your button immediately upon click
    el.target.disabled = true;
    // create list element and assign value
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = items[i].name
    // append list element to your <ul> list 
    document.getElementById('list-section').appendChild(li);
  }
 // append button to the DOM
  document.body.appendChild(btn)
}
```

```html
<ul id="list-section">

</ul>
```

Comment: What does JSON.stringify mean? Is that something used in javascript as well? I'm still in the beginning stages of learning javascript, I'm having trouble understanding the code. Is there a way to do this using only basic javascript? @EugenSunic

Comment: you shouldn't be using it. what do you want to display in your list?

Comment: I want 1 button for everything in the array. I want the name of the button to be the name of the item in the array. Then when the user clicks the button (can only click each button once), I want to display a list of the items clicked (technically it's the buttons name since each item's button will have the name of the item iteself) @EugenSunic

Comment: Once an item's button is clicked the names will display in a list. For example if you like cake and fries then list says Likes: cake,fries @Eugun_Sunic

Answer (score 0):

**HTML code:**

I created a div to append the buttons in it.

```
<html>
    <head>  
    </head>
    <body>
      <p id="likes">Likes: </p>
      <p id="clicks"></p>
      <div id="btn-container">
      </div>
    </body>
</html
```

>

**Js code:**

```
var items=[
{
name:"cake",
price:12
},
{
name:"fries",
price:10
},
{
name:"apple",
price:11
}
];



 for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

  var btnItems = document.createElement("button");
  btnItems.id = "btnItems"+i;
  var clicks = items[i].name;
  btnItems.innerHTML = clicks;

  document.getElementById("btn-container").appendChild(btnItems);
  console.log(btnItems);

  btnItems.addEventListener('click',function (el) {
  alert('here');
    el.disabled = true;
    clicks += items[i].name + i;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = "Items Clicked" + clicks;
  });
 }
```

Comment: well yes it is. i just included the relevent part of code.

Comment: I'm not getting any list displayed. @MrKhan

Answer (score -1):

As you have not provided a reproducible example I cannot test this, however, you should be able to use something like this. Please take note of the comments and amend where necessary.

```
window.onload = function() {

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        var btnItem = document.createElement("button");

        const name = item[i].name;            

        // Set the button id
        btnItem.id = `btnItem-${name}`;

        // Set the button text to the item name
        btnItem.innerHTML = name

        btnItem.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            event.target.disabled = true;

            // Do whatever you want here, e.g. add "name" to a list
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have provided all code in my files, I'm not sure what else to provide. Also I don't understand what btnItem.id = `btnItem-${name}`; means or what the event listener is for. @rhys_stubbs